# Migrating from AnythingSlider v1.2 to latest (v1.8.17)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, anythingslider

Here is the code of the slider I use now:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function formatText(index, panel) {
return index + "";


$(function () {

    $('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider({
         easing: "easeInOutExpo",        // Anything other than "linear" or "swing" requires the easing plugin
         autoPlay: true,                 // This turns off the entire FUNCTIONALY, not just if it starts running or not.
         delay: 5000,                    // How long between slide transitions in AutoPlay mode
         startStopped: false,            // If autoPlay is on, this can force it to start stopped
         animationTime: 600,             // How long the slide transition takes
         hashTags: true,                 // Should links change the hashtag in the URL?
         buildNavigation: false,         // If true, builds and list of anchor links to link to each slide
         pauseOnHover: true,             // If true, and autoPlay is enabled, the show will pause on hover
         startText: "Go",                // Start text
         stopText: "Stop",               // Stop text
         navigationFormatter: formatText // Details at the top of the file on this use (advanced use)
    });

    $("#slide-jump").click(function(){
         $('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(5);
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="anythingSlider">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>
         <li>
            <p><img alt="" width="582" height="255" src="IMAGELINK"></p>
            <div class="container"><a href="LINK" class="info">TEXT</a></div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p><img alt="" width="582" height="255" src="IMAGELINK"></p>
            <div class="container"><a href="LINK" class="info">TEXT</a></div>
         </li>                          
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Here is it working on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LUEwg/1/**

As you can see it uses jQuery (1.9.1), AnythingSlider (v1.2) and the Easing plugin (from "External Resources").
I'd like to migrate to the latest AnythingSlider version, which is [v.1.8.17](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/blob/master/js/jquery.anythingslider.js).

The problem is that my code requires some changes as it's not compatible as-is with AnythingSlider 1.8.17.

Here you can see the diff between old and new version:
http://diffchecker.com/3zadzbvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major differences in the versions are how the HTML is set up. As you shared above, the original version HTML would be set up as follows ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/5149/)):

```
<div class="anythingSlider">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>
         <li>
            <p><img alt="" width="582" height="255" src="IMAGELINK"></p>
            <div class="container"><a href="LINK" class="info">TEXT</a></div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p><img alt="" width="582" height="255" src="IMAGELINK"></p>
            <div class="container"><a href="LINK" class="info">TEXT</a></div>
         </li>                          
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

in the lastest version, the two `div` wrappers are added by the script, so start from the `ul`:

```
<ul id="slider">
   <li>
      <p><img alt="" width="582" height="255" src="IMAGELINK"></p>
      <div class="container"><a href="LINK" class="info">TEXT</a></div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p><img alt="" width="582" height="255" src="IMAGELINK"></p>
      <div class="container"><a href="LINK" class="info">TEXT</a></div>
   </li>                          
</ul>
```

Because of this, the css has been completely rewritten, so include the default css and add the following custom css:

```
/*** Set Slider dimensions here! Version 1.7+ ***/
/* added #slider li to make panels the same size in case "resizeContents" is false */
ul#slider, ul#slider li {
    width: 589px;
    height: 296px;
    list-style: none;
}

.anythingSlider.anythingSlider-default .arrow.forward a {
    background:url(http://lorenzoraffio.com/images/next.png) no-repeat left top;
    right:6px;
}
.anythingSlider.anythingSlider-default .arrow.back a {
    background:url(http://lorenzoraffio.com/images/prev.png) no-repeat left top;
}
.anythingSlider a {
    color:#706b6b;
}
.anythingSlider a.info {
    background:url(http://lorenzoraffio.com/images/marker1.png) no-repeat left 1px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:20px;
    float:right;
}

.anythingSlider a.info {
    background:url(http://lorenzoraffio.com/images/marker1.png) no-repeat left 1px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:20px;
    float:right;
}
.anythingSlider a.info:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#000;
}
.anythingSlider p {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.anythingSlider .container {
    padding:8px 25px 0 22px;
    width:auto;
}
```

The only change to your javascript was that I added the `buildStartStop: false` option instead of using the css: `#start-stop { display:none; }`

Comment: Thanks!! It works perfectly. :) Just out of curiosity, is needed the #&panel1-2 appended to the filename? Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Set the [`hashTags` option](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Navigation-options#hashtags-true) to `false`. You can find [full documentation here](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki)